# Add library dependencies to SBT, for SBT (not the project managed by SBT)

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to create a Task for SBT, so when I type "deploy" the task creates a .jar and then deploys it via SCP (I need an SSH library). The problem I'm struggling with is that I don't know know to add a library dependency (an SSH library) for build.sbt itself. I have 

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-vfs2" % "2.2"`

but this makes the library available to the project code, not the the SBT script "build.sbt" where I have to define the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

First, if you plan to re-implement the same functionality in multiple projects, the best thing to do would be to [create your own sbt plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html) - it is basically just another scala project, thus you add the dependency in the `build.sbt` of that project.

Second, if you only need it for one project, and don't want to publish a plugin for it. [**SBT is recursive**](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html) that means you can modify the **SBT** used to manage your project. This way you need to add your dependency to `./project/build.sbt` instead of `./build.sbt` - also I would recommend you write your task in a *Scala file* inside `project`.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds exactly like what's an sbt plugin ! Effectively a "sbt library".

For example, maybe https://github.com/shmishleniy/sbt-deploy-ssh would be of help to you ?

To use them, you'll need to edit the `plugins.sbt` file, not the `build.sbt` one

For example, for this ssh one, you'll need to add to your `plugins.sbt` file :

```
resolvers += "JAnalyse Repository" at "http://www.janalyse.fr/repository/"
addSbtPlugin("com.github.shmishleniy" % "sbt-deploy-ssh" % "0.1.4")
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. Although I may ask another question. I've tried to add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-vfs2/2.2 as a plugin, adding the resolver and the dependency, but when I reload sbt, it doesn't find the dependency out there. On the contrary, when I add the same dependency as a library dependency for my project, it works (the dependency is resolved). Do you have any clue on what can be happening here?